# What is "export default class Render" for in this code, why export and use it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

Its' my first time trying to create an electron app coming from a C/C++/Python with some django background and I am not quite understanding whats happening in this code. It's from this repo here. https://github.com/justinctlam/BabylonJS-Electron/blob/master/src/renderer.ts

Why is it exporting the class used in the same script file?
Is this somehow a requirement for electron?

```
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';

export default class Renderer {
    private _canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    private _engine: BABYLON.Engine;
    private _scene: BABYLON.Scene;

    createScene(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, engine: BABYLON.Engine) {
        this._canvas = canvas;

        this._engine = engine;

        // This creates a basic Babylon Scene object (non-mesh)
        const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
        this._scene = scene;

        // This creates and positions a free camera (non-mesh)
        const camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("camera1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10), scene);

        // This targets the camera to scene origin
        camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());

        // This attaches the camera to the canvas
        camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

        // This creates a light, aiming 0,1,0 - to the sky (non-mesh)
        const light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);

        // Default intensity is 1. Let's dim the light a small amount
        light.intensity = 0.7;

        // Our built-in 'sphere' shape. Params: name, subdivs, size, scene
        const sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere1", 16, 2, scene);

        // Move the sphere upward 1/2 its height
        sphere.position.y = 1;

        // Our built-in 'ground' shape. Params: name, width, depth, subdivs, scene
        const ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGround("ground1", 6, 6, 2, scene);
    }

    initialize(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
        const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
        this.createScene(canvas, engine);

        engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
            this._scene.render();
        });

        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            engine.resize();
        });
    }
}

const renderer = new Renderer();
renderer.initialize(document.getElementById('render-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement);
```

Comment: It's possibly not needed. It could be a redundant export that is never used. or maybe other places of the code also need that class?

Comment: as @dwjohnston said, Nothing special here, class is being exported just because other file can import it. If no file is importing this class then no need to add export statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class without export when you're on the same file. However the purpose of adding export is to reuse your code by other programm with the help of import.

There are two types of export one is named export and another is default export.

Here in your example you used default export. Default export are useful to export a single object, function or variable. You can use any name time of importing.

Just like in your case you can import

```
import Render from './renderer';
```

Here I am assuming you saved this file in renderer.js file. You can see when I am importing I am using different name as Render not Renderer. I able to do that because the class was using default export.

To Know more click [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)